# ChromeOptions to change the language from US to UK

Tags: c#, selenium

What are the ChromeOptions (C#) to change the default language of the browser from US to UK using Selenium v3 and Chrome v60+?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, I was using `cOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-GB");`
which wasn't changing the "Chrome is displayed in this language" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `lang` argument

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("lang=en-GB");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: It is in java same you can set in C#